# React application not connecting with local mqtt broker

Tags: reactjs, mqtt, publish-subscribe, mosca

I have setup a local mqtt broker using mosca as below

```
var mosca = require('mosca');
var settings = {
    port:1883
}

var server = new mosca.Server(settings);

server.on('ready', function(){
    console.log("ready");
});
```

Where I can publish and subscribe using the below respective codes

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.43.xxx');
client.on('connect', function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        client.publish('myTopic', 'Hello mqtt');
        console.log('Message Sent');
    }, 5000);
});
```

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.43.xxx')
client.on('connect', function () {
    client.subscribe('myTopic')
})
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    console.log(message.toString())
})
```

but When I try to connect form my react application it never establish connection. Where I was using *mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:8081* and it did work but when I changed the url to *mqtt://192.168.43.xxx:1883* it don't connect anymore.
What could be the problem?

EDIT : Any guide on setting up mqtt with web socket on node.js would be appreciated

Comment: You need to read the mosca documentation, it is VERY clear on how to setup websockets along with any number of other guides easily findable. Asking for links to off site tutorials is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of mosca I am now using aedes and the below code worked. So to use ws:// in browser we have to listen for ws port in backend/broker.

```
const aedes = require('aedes')();
const server = require('net').createServer(aedes.handle);

const ws = require('websocket-stream')


const port = 1883;

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`MQTT Broker running on port: ${port}`);
});

const wssPort = 1234
const host = '0.0.0.0' // localhost

var wsSslServer = require('http').createServer({})
ws.createServer({ server: wsSslServer}, aedes.handle)
wsSslServer.listen(wssPort, host, function () {
    console.log('WSS server listening on port', wssPort)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not use native MQTT from within the browser. To use MQTT, you need to use it over WebSockets.

so you should change the URL from `mqtt://192.168.43.xxx:1883` to `ws://192.168.43.xxx:[some other port number]`

Comment: I changed the port to 8080 in server also in react I change url to ws://192.168.43.xxx:8080 still it didnt work. So do I need to make any changes to my server file?

Comment: Yes, just changing the port doesn't change the protocol.